# Android IntentService is never called

Tags: java, android

I'm designing a application and need to use a IntentService to display the decibel levels measured by the phone. To do this I will use an IntentService. At the moment I implemented the service but cant seem to make it work. I implemented the following steps:

- Create a BroadcastReceiver in my MainActivity to retrieve the messages send my the IntentService (DbResponse) (Line 107)
- Register the service in my onCreate method of the MainActivity (Line 33-36)
- Create IntentService called SoundMeasurmentService and implement the onHandleIntent function. (SoundMeasurementSercie)
- Broadcast message from inside the onHandleIntent with the same setting used by the intentFilter

I put some system.outs inside the SoundMeasurementService and these are never printed. Makes me think the service is never called. But startSerice is called with the service so it should be call imo.

MainActiviyt.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.noisetubeinteractive2.EXTRA_MESSAGE";
private DbResponse dbResponse;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Registering service with category and filter (defined in SoundMeasuremntService)
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(DbResponse.ACTION_RESP);
    filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    dbResponse = new DbResponse();
    registerReceiver(dbResponse, filter);

    //Adding fragmets to the mainActivity
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.action_measurement:

            System.out.println("actoin_measurement clicked");
            return true;
        case R.id.action_profile:
            startProfile();
            System.out.println("action_profile clicked");
            return true;
        case R.id.action_settings:

            System.out.println("action_settngs clicked");
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    TextView textDbLvl;
    Intent mServiceIntent;

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container,false);

        textDbLvl = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.db_lvl); //Getting field that needs to be edited with response form broadcaster
        System.out.println("onCreateView of the PlaceholderFragment"); //This is printed

        mServiceIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), SoundMeasurementService.class); //Creating Intent to pass to Service
        mServiceIntent.putExtra(SoundMeasurementService.PARAM_IN_MSG, "This it the IN_MSG"); //Adding some dataString to the Intent to pass to service
        getActivity().startService(mServiceIntent); //Starting service with the intent

        System.out.println("Service is started");
        return rootView;
    }


}

public class DbResponse extends BroadcastReceiver {

    TextView textDbLvl;
    private String dbLvlString = "0";
    private static final String dbStringAppend = " db";
    public static final String ACTION_RESP = "com.noisetube.main.intent.action.MESSAGE_PROCESSED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        dbLvlString = intent.getStringExtra(SoundMeasurementService.PARAM_OUT_MSG); //Retrieving message from the intend by the Serice 
        System.out.println("Received from broadcast: " + dbLvlString);
        textDbLvl.setText(dbLvlString + dbStringAppend); //Set layout to received message
    }
}

public void sendMessage(View view) {
    //Resoponding on teh button click 'Send'
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class); //Intent used to start another activity (binding between seperate components)
                                                                    //2nd par: class of component witch to deliver the intent
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message); //Values linked to data, EXTRA_MESSAGE should be added as public final static

    startActivity(intent);
}

public void startProfile() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, NewProfileActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

}

SoundMeasurmentService.java

```
public class SoundMeasurementService extends IntentService {

private int dbLvl= 10;
public static final String DB_LVL = "DB_LVL";
public static final String PARAM_IN_MSG = "inMsg";
public static final String PARAM_OUT_MSG = "outMsg";
//TODO create soundmeter class

public SoundMeasurementService() {
    super("SoundMeasurementService");
    System.out.println("SoundMeasurmentService Created");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent workIntent) {

    System.out.println("Called onHandleIntent");
    String msg = workIntent.getStringExtra(PARAM_IN_MSG);
    Intent broadcatIntent = new Intent();
    broadcatIntent.setAction(DbResponse.ACTION_RESP);
    broadcatIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    broadcatIntent.putExtra(PARAM_OUT_MSG, msg + "and msg out");
    sendBroadcast(broadcatIntent);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was possible to fix this error by changing the service declaration in the Androidmanifest.xml file.

Old code:

```
<service android:name=".SoundMeasurementService" android:exported="false"/>
```

New code:

```
<service android:name="com.noisetube.main.SoundMeasurementService" android:exported="false"/>
```